# Can't execute Shellscript successfully using getruntime.exec()

Tags: java, shell

I have written a code to execute a script from java :

```
 String wrapper_script=homedir+"/blast_distribute.sh "+" --seqs="+seqs+" --i="+formobj.getUpFile().getFileName()+"  "+formobj.getSelected_program();

 script_exec=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(wrapper_script);
```

This works perfect for me as command is executed successfully. Now I need to run this command as other user so I need to execute a command in a format like :

> su username -c 'command'

SO I have edited above script_exec string as :

```
String wrapper_script1="su - "+username+" -c "+"'"+wrapper_script+"'";
```

I have printed wrapper_script1 which diplays:

> su - abhijeet -c '/home/abhijeet//blast_distribute.sh  --seqs=1562
>   --i=mPS_0.contigs.fasta'

If I run same command directly on Linux,It works exactly as I need.But When I am running through :

`script_exec=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(wrapper_script1);`
It does't work properly ,In my error stream I get error as

> su: unrecognized option '--seqs=1562' Try `su --help' for more
>   information.

I have tried a lot but could't resolve the issue.What can be the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use multiple parameters run for this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-", username, "-c",
        homedir + "/blast_distribute.sh " + " --seqs=" + seqs + " --i=" + formobj.getUpFile().getFileName() + "  " + formobj.getSelected_program()
});
```

You're getting the error, because `'` is not treated here as a enclosing characters, but as a parameters for `su` command.

Let's look into details. When you type into console some command like `su - jsmith -c 'aba --cabga'`, what you're doing is: "run command `su` with such an arguments: `-`, `jsmith`, `-c`, `aba --caba` (one argument for multiple words)".

The same thing you should do in your Java code. There's special command in Java API for running the concrete command with concrete arguments instead of parsing line as shell do: [Runtime.exec(String[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])): the first argument is command, the next are the arguments. That's what we do in this code block.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , in su username -c 'command' ,command is quoted ,I need to pass quoted command to it.

Comment: You should give this a try. What you call "quoted" is just a signal to your shell, that this set of characters should be treated as one argument.

Comment: @AbhijeetPanwar then 127 is a return value of `su` command. You should look at the output. When I run `man su` and look for `127` output code, I see this line "The requested command could not be executed". Maybe your script is not executable?

Comment: I did't get required output ,In my error Stream I am getting -bash: /home/abhijeet//blast_distribute.sh  --seqs=1562 --i=mPS_0.contigs.fasta : No such file or directory,                     but file and directory exists ,thet worked with my 1st syntax.

Comment: @AbhijeetPanwar ooops, I forgot `-c` flag, see the updated answer.

Comment: Really , Thanks a lot for this.I was facing this issue for long :( Can you just explaing little that what this syntax exactly does?How is that different than my syntax?

Comment: Okay, I'll try to extend an answer.

Comment: @AbhijeetPanwar added an explanation, maybe you'll find it useful.